# Plumbing water pressure

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure

I turned off water supply to house to replace shower cartridge.  Water off for three or so hours.  Turned water back on and "flushed" the lines.  A few days later, turned on pool filler and got low pressure and almost no pressure everywhere else in house during fillup.  HELP!

Comment: Did the pressure go back to normal if you turn off pool filler?

Answer (score 1):

Pool filler is leaking somewhere. I know the cartridge replacement seems suspect, but I believe that's just a coincidence.